# Error "panic: attempt to copy freed scalar" when using Getopt::Long

Tags: perl

I get the error:

```
panic: attempt to copy freed scalar a121fb4 to a156be8 at ./p.pl line 13.
```

when I run the following program (`p.pl`):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

main(@ARGV);

sub main {
  GetOptions ();

  print "\@ARGV=@ARGV\n";
  my $arg=shift;
}
```

when using one or more command line arguments, for example `p.pl 1` gives the error.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Which version of Perl (and platform) are you using?  This runs with no errors on Perl 5.16.3 on Linux Debian Wheezy. Update:  I forgot to add the argument; I do get that error as well.

Comment: `@_` gets empty after `GetOptions()` and same error is on 5.20 and 5.10.1. `@ARGV` is unaffected.

Comment: I see the same error on 5.8.9, 5.18.2, and 5.21.2 as well.  Looks like a longstanding problem.  I suggest using perlbug to send a Perl bug report.  There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Don't bother. There's already numerous tickets about bugs that are due to the stack not being reference counted.

Comment: @Diab Jerius, There's definitely something wrong in his code, and fixing the error (as shown in Miller's answer) eliminates the problem.

Comment: @ikegami, I agree, conceptually the code has problems (as Miller pointed out), but it's valid Perl code and it shouldn't trigger a Perl panic. That's the sense of my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug that occurs because you're passing `@ARGV`.

`@_` is set to aliases of the values of `@ARGV`.   `GetOptions` then performs operations on the original `@ARGV`, so your later `shift @_` has issues.

Here are two solutions.

1. Perform `GetOptions` before calling the sub:

   ```
   GetOptions();  # Manipulate @ARGV before passing it.

   main(@ARGV);

   sub main {
       print "\@ARGV=@ARGV\n";
       my $arg = shift;
   }
   ```
2. Don't bother passing `@ARGV` because it's global anyway:

   ```
   main();   # Don't pass @ARGV since it's global

   sub main {
       GetOptions();

       print "\@ARGV=@ARGV\n";
       my $arg = shift @ARGV;
   }
   ```

Comment: I am because the OP did.  No other reason.  Why would you?  Because you could still perform error checking looking for unexpected command line arguments.  Yes, he would need to add an `or die`, but perhaps he removed those in creating a `MCVE`.

Comment: It is interesting that taking reference (or just `print \@_`) before calling a function eliminates the error.

Comment: Good catch (Yet another bug caused by Perl's stack not being reference counted)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the details I just sent as a "bug-circumvent request" to Getopt::Long
will help clarify this situation:

https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=120562

This is sensitive to trigger: without the "my $a" the bug stops showing up.

Post Scriptum: I realize Getopt::Long mentions @ARGV many times in its documentation, with remarks such as "@ARGV will always be empty upon successful return of GetOptions()". A "temporary" circumvent solution might be for Getopt::Long to warn against this core Perl bug, and programmers should use something like Getopt::Long::GetOptionsFromArray([@ARGV]) instead, if they want to be able to use @ARGV after a Getopt::Long use.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change either your function signature or your shift targets `GetOptionsFromArray` seems to do the trick.

```
main(@ARGV);

sub main {
    GetOptionsFromArray(\@_);  # Manipulate copy of @ARGV that shift will operate on
    my $arg = shift;
}
```