# Modulino package name added to @_

Tags: perl, modulino

Consider the following basic Perl modulino:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
package Toto;

__PACKAGE__->run(@ARGV) unless caller();

sub run 
{
  print "@ARGV";
  print "@_";
}

1;
```

If I run it on the command line, I get:

```
$ ./Toto.pm 1 2 3
1 2 3
Toto 1 2 3
```

If I call it from a test:

```
$ perl -MToto -le 'Toto::run(1,2,3)'    
#first line blank - no ARGV set
1 2 3
```

In other words, the contents of @_ inside run() changes depending on how the function is called.

Can you explain what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
__PACKAGE__->run(@ARGV)
```

is equivalent to

```
Toto->run(1,2,3)
```

This is a class method call. Method calls pass the invocant (the value to which the LHS of the `->` evaluated) as the first argument. This differs from

```
Toto::run(1,2,3)
```

which is a simple sub call. The following will call `run` as a sub:

```
run(@ARGV) unless caller();
```

Comment: You could also remove the line and replace `sub main` with `if (caller)`.

Answer (score 6):

You mean why is "Toto" in @_?  Because you are calling it as a class method, so it implicitly passes the class as the first parameter.  If you don't want to do that, just do `run(@ARGV) unless caller()` instead.

Comment: Note that there could be a problem using this call when also using `Getopt::Long::GetOptions`, see [Error “panic: attempt to copy freed scalar” when using Getopt::Long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508899/error-panic-attempt-to-copy-freed-scalar-when-using-getoptlong)

Comment: @HåkonHægland a modulino (also sometimes called a progmod) shouldn't be calling GetOptions in the code that is run when it is used as a module, not a program.  But your point is taken: passing globals in general is a bad idea because they can change out from under you.